# Append JSON from Counters

Tags: json, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import json
>>> a = Counter({'aaa': 310, 'bbbb': 42})
>>> sample_list = ['unit_1', 'unit_2']
>>> mydict = {'data': []}
>>> for elemnt in sample_list:
...   for k,v in a.items():
...     mydict['data'].append({"key": k, "value": v})
...
>>> json_data = json.dumps(mydict)
>>> print(json_data)
{"data": [{"key": "aaa", "value": 310}, {"key": "bbbb", "value": 42}, {"key": "aaa", "value": 310}, {"key": "bbbb", "value": 42}]}
>>>
```

what I need to achieve is:

```
{"data": [{"unit_1": [{"key": "aaa", "value": 310}, {"key": "bbbb", "value": 42}]},{"unit_2": [{"key": "aaa", "value": 310}, {"key": "bbbb", "value": 42}]}]}
```

or

```
[{"unit_1": [{"key": "aaa", "value": 310}, {"key": "bbbb", "value": 42}]},{"unit_2": [{"key": "aaa", "value": 310}, {"key": "bbbb", "value": 42}]}]
```

My 'Counter' is updated on each iteration of outer loop (not shown here), so I out it here as example.

Stuck at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add data in a list. If I correctly understand the requirements, this should return the desired output:

```
from collections import Counter
import json
a = Counter({'aaa': 310, 'bbbb': 42})
sample_list = ['unit_1', 'unit_2']
mydict = {'data': []}
for elemnt in sample_list:
   l = []
   for k,v in a.items():
      l.append({"key": k, "value": v})
   mydict['data'].append({elemnt: l})

json_data = json.dumps(mydict)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that is what I was looking for